# Scroll / Jump to id without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I have search a lot of topics for a usable solution.
 But dont found something. Most scripts are just too cluttered for my purposes.
 Seeking a solution based only on Javascript. **In my project it is not possible to use jQuery.** 
I need a jump or scroll to id.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
//here has to go function
</script>
</head>
```

MY call is:

```
<a onclick="function_call+targetname"><img src="image1" alt="name1"></a>
<a onclick="function_call+targetname"><img src="image2" alt="name2"></a>
<a onclick="function_call+targetname"><img src="image3" alt="name3"></a>
```

So i have to use onclick event in my navigation.

Now onclick i want to jump or scroll to a div id in my page:

```
<div id="target1">some content</div>
<div id="target2">some content</div>
<div id="target3">some content</div>
```

It is very important: html anchor not work unfortunately. Otherwise everything would be pretty easy. 
I have use bevore simply:

```
onclick="window.location.hash='target';"
```

But i have restrictions in eBay. They dont allow this simple code.

Also I cant call an external javascript (only use JS in head area). Furthermore, it is not possible to use : "cookie.", "cookie", "replace (", IFRAME, META or includes) and base href.

It can not be hard with a bit of JS jump to a specific point. 
I do not need special effects.

Does anyone have a slim and helpful solution?

> I Have found a solution by my self and thanks to Oxi. I follow your
>   way.
>
> For all those interested in my solution:

```
<head> <script type="text/javascript"> function scroll(element){   
var ele = document.getElementById(element);   
window.scrollTo(ele.offsetLeft,ele.offsetTop); } </script> </head>
```

> Navigation Call:

```
<a onclick='scroll("target1");'><img src="image1" alt="name1"></a>
```

> Now you can jump to a div with called ID

```
<div id="target1">CONTENT</div>
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "html anchor not work" - how did you implement it??

Answer (score 207):

Maybe You should try scrollIntoView.

```
document.getElementById('id').scrollIntoView();
```

This will scroll to your Element.

Comment: Just a note: When using the `id`, make sure that you don't prepend it with `#` sign. For example, if you want to jump to a div with ID `myDiv`, then the code would be: `document.getElementById('myDiv').scrollIntoView();`

Comment: this is an experimental feature, working just on Firefox at the current time
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: Check compatibility here : developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 108):

if you want smooth scrolling add `behavior` configuration.

```
document.getElementById('id').scrollIntoView({
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

Comment: how can we solve it when we have so many id’s on a single page??

Comment: @GoodnessGoodnessChi, ids should be unique. Use classes instead.

Comment: and you can use querySelectorAll to get all the elements with the same class.

Comment: The neat answer!

Comment: This scrolls a bit too far since we have a nav bar at the top.

Answer (score 24):

Add the function:

```
function scrollToForm() {
  document.querySelector('#form').scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
}
```

Trigger the function:

```
<a href="javascript: scrollToForm();">Jump to form</a>
```

Answer (score 9):

Oxi's answer is just wrong.¹

What you want is:

```
var container = document.body,
element = document.getElementById('ElementID');
container.scrollTop = element.offsetTop;
```

Working example:

```
(function (){
  var i = 20, l = 20, html = '';
  while (i--){
    html += '<div id="DIV' +(l-i)+ '">DIV ' +(l-i)+ '</div>';
    html += '<a onclick="document.body.scrollTop=document.getElementById(\'DIV' +i+ '\').offsetTop">';
    html += '[ Scroll to #DIV' +i+ ' ]</a>';
    html += '<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />';
  }
  document.write( html );
})();
```

¹ I haven't got enough reputation to comment on his answer

Comment: Note that offsetTop is measured from the element's immediate parent. You can use element.parentElement to get the parent and get its offset if needed.

Answer (score 4):

on anchor tag use href and not onclick

```
<a href="#target1">asdf<a>
```

And div:

```
<div id="target1">some content</div>
```

Comment: you are already using anchor tag <a> in your html ..so suggested you .

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me

- Give id to each section
- In Javascript file create a function
- Call that function using onclick in the nav links

```js
let About = () =>document.getElementById('About').scrollIntoView();
```

```css
.about-link {
 min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-link">
<a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" onclick="About()">About</a>
</div>
<section id="About">
Here is about section
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

below code might help you

```
var objControl=document.getElementById("divid");
objControl.scrollTop = objControl.offsetTop;
```

Comment: Should it be `document.body.scrollTop` rather than `objControl.scrollTop`?

Comment: @Oxi var i set up in head area and onclick i use ?

Comment: @user1805546 in your onclick listener  use the id of div for example 'target1'

Comment: @Alexander Pavlov it is element scrolltop .. more info @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollTop

Comment: It's a good idea to always double-check your solutions: http://jsfiddle.net/nPegf/1/. Also, MDN says, "If the element can't be scrolled (e.g. it has no overflow or if the element is non-scrollable), scrollTop is set to 0." That said, `scrollTop` makes sense for a _scrollable_ element, i.e. one that has a scrollbar. I'm pretty sure `objControl` does not.

Comment: @oxi I think it should be document.body.scrollTop instead of objControl.scrollTop because we want to scroll the page and not inside the component

Answer (score 2):

you can do it smoothly even without javascript code!
just add `scroll-behavior: smooth;` to scrollable element.
example:

```css
#parent {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#top {
  min-height: 1000px;
  max-width: 100px;
  text-wrap: wrap;
}

#footer {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="top">
    <a href="#footer">move to bottom</a> context is here! Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
    type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
    Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
    dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm super surprised no one has shown you a way to do it without even using JavaScript code.

Add an ID to your element, then in your link tag add the href with the ID Name

Example

```
<a href="#AboutMe">About Me</a>

<div id="AboutMe">
// Some code
</div>
```

> Note: This is only to jump, not to scroll!